# Typhoon DI: Is there any way to find an assembly by class name at runtime?

Tags: typhoon

Using Typhoon dependency injection, is there any way, regular or a hack, to find an assembly by it's class name in runtime?
I'm required to load a configuration from a file in one assembly, and that configuration would tell me which other assemblies to use to produce some components needed in the current assembly. Also I don't have all assemblies code (classes) available as I'm working on a reusable (library) code, so it needs to be dynamic and in runtime.
Any way at all?

Thanks.

EDIT:

The thing I tried to do is a bit contradictory. I wanted to access other initial assemblies from one initial assembly, while all of them were in the process of being initialized (the point when swizzled setAppDelegate is called, plist TyphoonInitialAssemblies is read and assemblies created). No assembly is activated at that point.

But, managed to do it in a bit strange way, by instantiating an assembly using a class name [[NSClassFromString(assemblyClassName) alloc] init] and performing a selector on the returned object. And it works as long as that assembly is already initialized (appears first in the plist). So, to repeat, all this happens during initial assembly creation (swizzled setAppDelegate).

I'm just not sure if this approach is safe?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Assemblies in Typhoon serve two purposes:**

- Build time: A place to declare the key actors in your architecture and how they interact with other actors. You can use modularization here to organize information in a logical manner - typically to reflect a layered architecture.
- Run time: They act as a factory to retrieve built instances according to the rules declared at build-time.

At build-time all of the information goes into `TyphoonComponentFactory`, which is what is able to produce instances. On this class there are methods to retrieve components by type or by key - where key is a method name from one of your assembly classes.

(Side note: In Typhoon it is easy to declare multiple actors of the same type).

Then, to avoid the use of 'magic strings' assemblies (just the interface) can act as a facade in front of the `TyphoonComponentFactory` to retrieve instances. What happens here is that Objective-C message forwarding is used.

**This means that:**

- As long as all of the rules for building instances are given,  `TyphoonComponentFactory` can build them.
- (Objective-C only): You can cast any `TyphoonComponentFactory` instance to one of your assembly interfaces and call methods on it. If there's a rule to build an instance matching the method name (and any args), then it will be returned, otherwise 'no component for key' is raised.

This information is of a general nature - I suspect that if you know how things work behind the scenes, you'll know the kinds of things you can do, and what approaches are appropriate. If you'd like more specifics, please edit your question and I'll provide them.

Comment: Edited my question to add more context and a possible solution about which I'm not sure if it is safe to do. But what you already wrote helped me a lot (would upvote, but no reputation). Thank you very much! :)